# I'm having trouble adding these elements of my array together. the dash seems to inhibit the addition of each variable

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the following code to add each number in the element separately and not the whole array together but the dash seems to stop the loop from calculating the total sum of each element. I can't seem to make it so it'll except any length of number for the variable. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```js
var creditNum = [];
creditNum[0] = ('4916-2600-1804-0530');
creditNum[1] = ('4779-252888-3972');
creditNum[2] = ('4252-278893-7978');
creditNum[3] = ('4556-4242-9283-2260');

var allNum = [];
var total = 0;
var num = 0;
var cnt = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < creditNum.length; i++) {
  num = creditNum[i];

  for (var j = 1; j <= num.length; j++) {
    var num = creditNum[i].substring(cnt, j);
    console.log(creditNum[i].charAt(cnt));
    console.log(cnt, j);

    cnt = cnt + 1;
  }
  if (num != "-") j = j++;
  console.log(parseInt(num));


}
console.log(total);
```

Comment: Please walk through your code with a debugger. By the way, what output are you expecting exactly?

Comment: Have you tried any of the answers yet?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the intent is to add `'4916-2600-1804-0530'` and output the value as `49`, then the following modification will achieve that.

```js
var creditNum = ['4916-2600-1804-0530', '4779-252888-3972', '4252-278893-7978','4556-4242-9283-2260'];

for (var i = 0; i < creditNum.length; i++) {
  var num = creditNum[i].replace(/\-/g, '');
  var total = 0;

  for (var j = 0; j < num.length; j++) {
    total += Number(num[j]);
  }
  
  console.log(creditNum[i], total);
}
```

Using native array methods, the code can be refactored as the following.

```js
var creditNumbers = ['4916-2600-1804-0530', '4779-252888-3972', '4252-278893-7978','4556-4242-9283-2260'];

creditNumbers.forEach(function(creditNumber) {
  var num = creditNumber.replace(/\-/g, '').split('');
  var total = num.reduce(function(tally, val) {
    return tally += Number(val);
  }, 0);
  
  console.log(creditNumber, total);
});
```